# Percentage field semantics - 1 or 100 for 100%

Tags: fields

What should a user input into a Percentage field to state "100%"? Is there a defined semantics or is this something the creator of the fields has to configure by the amount of decimals and validation rules?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

User input for a percentage field is to represent the percentage as a whole number.

- .1 = .1%
- 1 = 1%
- 10 = 10%
- 100 = 100%

Worth mentioning also that the value retrieved from the DB comes out in the same format, you need to convert by dividing by 100 yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To state 100% you just need to input 100 in a percent field.

When you will convert this value to an integer then it will be divided by 100 and you will get 1.