# Confused by default value of percent fields

Tags: custom-field

As [asked and learned here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50103/percentage-field-semantics-1-or-100-for-100) you need to enter `100` into a percent field to get `100%`. BUT to set a percent field to `100%` by default you need to enter `1` as **default value**. Otherwise it will result in `10.000`.

**Why that?**

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why but this is how saleforce handle Percentage fields. Salesforce will multiply any value you set in percentage field to 100. This will happen only when you use a percentage field in formula editors or apex code i.e 1.00 for 100% while from UI it will ask to give a percentage value directly i.e 100 for 100%.