# Percent type issue

Tags: formula, formula-field, percent

I have percent field per. I am using this field in apex coding for calculation purpose.

My formula in code is:

```
Field_A__c = Field_B__c * Percent__c
```

Suppose `Percent__c = 75` (i.e 75%) and `Field_B__c = 35`. In that case, `Field_A__c` should be `35 * 0.75 = 26.25`. But it is actually doing `35 * 75 = 2625`.

What can we do here?

Comment: Related [post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50103/percentage-field-semantics-1-or-100-for-100)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just divide by 100.

```
35 * 75 / 100 = 26.25
```

So use a formula of

```
Field_B__c * Percent__c / 100
```

Comment: thats perfect. Thank you. This is the matter of logic.